# I have genrated the pdf file now i dont want to download the file but i want to upload the file directly on ftp using java

Tags: java

So i am rendering the html to pdf file now every time i run the code the file get downloded and its working fine but instead of downloading i want to directly upload on ftp server as soon as file get generated
Below is my code like this

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public String test(@Context HttpServletResponse response){

String strHtml ="<html><body>"Here is my html"</body></html>";
String filename=test.pdf";
DocumentBuilder builder   =   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
      @SuppressWarnings( "deprecation")
      org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse( new StringBufferInputStream(strHtml.replaceAll("&" , "&amp;")));
     ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
      renderer.setDocument((org.w3c.dom.Document) doc, null);

      renderer.layout();

           response.setHeader( "Cache-Control","private" );
           response.setHeader( "Pragma","expires" );
           response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename  + "\"");

      renderer.createPDF(response.getOutputStream());
      response.getOutputStream().flush();
      response.getOutputStream().close();
```

}

Comment: So return some random success response and call a service to upload to the server. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library for working with FTP. Here's a simple [FTP client example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/TFTPExample.java).